# I want to store my firestore value as number but it is being stored as string

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to store my collection values all my values are stored as string i want to store my  price and servings value as a number in firestore.

So can someone tell me what to add or change so that it is stored as a number value.

Code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebaseConfig'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { addDoc, collection } from 'firebase/firestore'
import './contact.css';

const Contact = () => {

const [servings, setServings] = useState("");
const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
"");

const userCollectionRef = collection(db, "mastermenu")

const handleSubmit = () => {
addDoc(userCollectionRef,{
   
    servings: servings,
    price: price,
   
}).then(() => {
  if(!alert("form Submitted Successfully!!!"));
})
}

<label>Servings</label>
  <select
    onChange={(e) => setServings(e.target.value)}>
    <option value="">Select Servings</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

   <label>Price</label>
    <input
    
    placeholder=" ₹ Enter Amount"
    onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)} />``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your states are initiated as strings. You can convert them to a number by wrapping them with Javascript's **Number** method:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
addDoc(userCollectionRef,{
   
    servings: Number(servings),
    price: Number(price),
   
}).then(() => {
  if(!alert("form Submitted Successfully!!!"));
})
}
```

Comment: i want to store true false dropdown option as boolean in firestore can you help with that if possible

Comment: You can use a simple condition to convert string true and false to boleans. 
like this: value === "true"

Comment: yeah i got it now

Comment: Hi ali, if possible please take a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73257631/reactjs-firebase-convert-string-to-map