# Reactjs firebase convert string to map

Tags: reactjs, firebase

In my app in reactjs i have created an array steps, where the user can add the steps to prepare a recipe and it will be stored in firebase, my problem is the steps are being stored directly as strings in the array, what i want is them to be stored inside a map. Can someone please tellme how to do this.

[image: steps firebase]

[image: map firebase].

I want them to be like this.

Code :

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
steps: []
})

addDoc(recipesCollectionRef, form)

setForm({
  steps: []
})
const handleStep = (e, i) => {
const stepsClone = [...form.steps]

stepsClone[i] = e.target.value

setForm({
  ...form,
  steps: stepsClone
})
}

const handleStepCount = () => {
setForm({
  ...form,
  steps: [...form.steps, ""]
})
}
<label>Steps</label>
          {
            form.steps.map((step, i) => (
              <textarea 
                type="text"
                key={i}
                value={step} 
                onChange={e => handleStep(e, i)} />
            ))
          }
          <button type="button" onClick={handleStepCount}>Add step</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.target.value` is a string. The current code appears to be saving an array of strings with `stepsClone[i] = e.target.value`. If you want to save an array of objects then the code needs to do something a little different.

Example:

```
const handleStep = (e, i) => {
  setForm(form => {
    const stepsClone = [...form.steps];

    stepsClone[i] = {
      from: e.target.value,
      to: // another value ???
    };

    return {
      ...form,
      steps: stepsClone,
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to add seprerate value to from and to , like from and to aur hours i want them to add minutes to them, so is it possible to create two input feilds whose value can be added to from and to, if required i can ask this as a seperate question.

Comment: @siddhantkumar Yes, I think it's possible, but also yes, a separate/new question would be preferable here since (a) it's a bit off-topic for the specific question you posted here, and (b) I'd ask questions like what is the new object you want to save and what are you rendering from it? These you could provide us as a [mcve] in a new post. If you create a new post feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I'll check when I have availability.