# React Js firebase addition function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

This is connected to a previous question i asked you can find it here.
[Reactjs firebase convert string to map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73257631/reactjs-firebase-convert-string-to-map)
In my react app the data is being stored in firebase as an array map.

The two fields which are being mapped inside the slots array are from and to. What i require is to create two separate fields from minute and to minute, when the user adds data in from minute the value gets added to from field and that final value becomes stored in firebase. Same with to and to minute fields. ex: if user inputs in from 6 and in from minute 12 the value stored in firestore will be 18.

Code :

```
addDoc(slotsCollectionRef, form)

setForm({
  slots: []
})

const handleSlot = (e, i) => {
const { name, value } = e.target;
setForm(form => ({
  ...form,
  slots: form.slots.map((el, index) => index === i
    ? {
      ...el,
      [name]:  parseInt(value),
    }
    : el
  ),
  }));
 };

 const handleSlotCount = () => {
 setForm({
  ...form,
  slots: [...form.slots, ""]
})
}

  <label><b>From</b></label>
                 <br />
              <input
                type="number"
                name="from"
                value={slot.from}
                onChange={e => handleSlot(e, i)}
              />
```

Comment: I doubt someone will respond. I can't understand what you want to active other people, probably to.

Comment: can you check it now, i have edited the question to better explain it.

Comment: So am I understanding correctly that you've an array of objects (*form.slots*) of shape `{ from: number, to: number }` and you want to aggregate total `from` and `to` values and send a single object/update to the firebase backend?

Comment: No, I want to create two additional inputs from minute and to minute only for react, not save them in firestore. The value of from minute will be added to from and saved in firestore.

Comment: Ex; user inputs 4 in from and 8 in from from minute so from in firestore will be saved as 12. From(4) + from minute (8) = 12 (final value saved in firestore)

Comment: And is this for each `form.slots` array element? You want four inputs for each, "from" and "fromMinute", and "to" and "toMinute", and the "from" and "to" input values come from firebase, and the "fromMinute" and "toMinute" are local state, and when any of these are updated you want to add the "from" and "fromMinute" together into "from", and add "to" and "toMinute" together, and store both back into firebase as "from" and "to"? The code snippet has a single input, can you edit the code to more accurately represent what you are trying to do? It may help resolve our confusion.

Comment: no i only want 2 inputs from minute  for each from and tominute for each to element. the second part of your comment is correct. "the "from" and "to" input values come from firebase, and the "fromMinute" and "toMinute" are local state, and when any of these are updated you want to add the "from" and "fromMinute" together into "from", and add "to" and "toMinute" together, and store both back into firebase as "from" and "to"? "

Comment: Here is a video to better explain it https://drive.google.com/file/d/1STeYSFLKBlII0C2HrzRD1l2ZPZUzXEd8/view?usp=sharing, inside of adding slots one time i want users to be able to add multiple times, hence the array map.

Comment: In that video there are 4 inputs, but they appear to be labeled hours and minutes. I don't understand how a user can enter four values if you only want two inputs.

Comment: You can enter 4 values but only 2 values will. Be saved In firebase from and to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247210/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-siddhant-kumar).

Comment: Why not use timepicker? It would make things easier, right?